# gridview adding a new row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with item templates bound to an sql data source. I need to add a new row on the textchanged event of my last textbox itemtemplate in the specific row. the problem is when i add a new row, the previous row values, entered by me are not displayed. Can someone please give me the code to retain those values. please keep the code in c#.

thanks

```
SqlDataAdapter ddm = new SqlDataAdapter(cdm);
DataTable dss = new DataTable();
ddm.Fill(dss);
GridView1.DataSource = dss;
GridView1.DataBind();
for (int i = 0; i <= dss.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
   DropDownList dd1 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("ddl1");

   dd1.DataSource = dss;
   dd1.DataTextField = "Material_Details";
   dd1.DataBind();
}

cn.Close();
//code for new row

DataRow dr = dss.NewRow;
dss.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: i created a datarow as a new row and added it to my datatable. but the previous row values are gone once the new row is added.

Comment: @RAHUL: What he means is, show us the code you have so far.  We can't suggest improvements to code we haven't seen.

Comment: You need to add this code to the question.  Edit your question, and clearly show the code you've tried so far

Comment: forget about the dropdownlist i added....

Comment: Can you post the markup for your gridview?

Comment: Did you have search the answers in SO first? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+row+gridview

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are entering values and then trigger a post-back that adds a new row.  You need during the post-back to grab the values you entered and *save* / redisplay them, or they are lost.

You save them the same as any other way, by looking for their _Changed event handlers (or in Load() with an `if(IsPostBack){ save values }`) and saving them / adding them to your DataTable to be displayed in the grid when you re-bind it.